# How can one construct $f(x)$ such that this definate integral is always true?

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

I have the integral,

$$I=\int_{a_1}^{a_2} x f(x) dx=0$$

Given that $a_1$ and $a_2$ are arbitrary real numbers with $a_2 > a_1>0 $ and $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a_1,a_2]$.

I am trying to find a family of continuous functions $f$ for which given $a_1$ and $a_2$ the integral $I=0$.

If $xf(x)$ is changes sign in $[a_1,a_2]$ then this is possible but I don't know how to construct $f(x)$ such that this is true.

Comment: Let $f(x) = g(x)/x$ and $g$ be an 'odd' function in the sense that is odd with respect to the origin $(a_1+a_2)/2$

Comment: By "$I$ is *always* true", do you mean that you wonder which continuous functions $f$ satisfy $I=0$ for all $a_1,a_2,$ or that given $a_1,a_2,$ you want a family of continuous functions $f$ for which $I=0?$

Comment: I am trying to find a family of continuous functions  $f$ for which given $a_1$ and $a_2$,  $I=0$.

Comment: Still not sure to understand. But I guess that by "family of [...]functions f for which given a1 and a2, I=0", you mean "given a1 and a2, family of [...]functions f for which I=0".
... Despite your "the equation cannot hold *for all choices a1
 and a2*
 if f(x)≠0
".

Comment: Still not clear. Are a1 and a2 fixed, and you want to find a bunch of $f$s for which that integral is zero, or do you want to find some $f$ for which that integral is zero, no matter what values a1 and a2 have?

Answer (score 4):

Given $0<a_1<a_2,$ for *any* continuous function $h$ on $[a_1,a_2],$ define
$$J:=\int_{a_1}^{a_2}h(x)\,dx,$$
$$g(x):=h(x)-\frac J{a_2-a_1}$$
and
$$f(x):=\frac {g(x)}x.$$
Then, $\int_{a_1}^{a_2}xf(x)\,dx=0.$ Conversely, any solution $f$ can be obtained that way, from $h(x):=g(x):=xf(x).$